# How to clear the ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am using expandable list view as a tree view structure and it needs to be updated continuously but as I can not clear the current expandable list view, it shows the previous data along with new data. Like if I minimize and again open app there is duplicate data in list view.

Comment: on your update trigger event, call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter.

Comment: can you please tell me about the update trigger event?

Comment: can you share the code?, I need to see how you are setting the data for the expandable listview.

Answer (score 0):

```
yourExpandableListView.setAdapter((BaseExpandableListAdapter)null);
```

Answer (score 0):

ExpandableListAdapter adapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(); //or what ever adapter you use/created listView.setAdapter(adapter)
Please try this

Comment: I believe we can just set an adapter with it and I have done the same but I want to clear the current list if the method that is forming the list is called again.

Comment: Before adapter set clear arraylist which is set in your adapter with null check

Comment: can you please write a brief syntax what you trying to convey?